# .Net 3.5 silent installer?

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, installation, redistributable

Is there a redistributable .Net 3.5 installation package that is a silent installer?

Or alternatively, is there a switch that can be passed to the main redistributable .Net 3.5 installer to make it silent?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
dotnetfx35setup.exe /q /norestart
```

see the .net deployment guide at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc160716.aspx

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 10 you need to do following

```
DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:NetFx3 /All /LimitAccess /Source:"Path\To\microsoft-windows-netfx3-ondemand-package"
```

You can find thoose packages under sources\sxs of a Windows DVD

Comment: This worked for me, but used: Dism /online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:NetFx3